# Averaging In SQL When Multiples Values Possible In A Row

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions, average

I want to try and average orders based on unit price and quantity. The unit price changes per order, but the product can be the same.

So, I am trying to do something similar to the following example.

Say I have this data set:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ OrderID ║ ProductName ║ UnitPrice ║ Quantity ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║ Apple       ║ 10.00     ║       10 ║
║       2 ║ Apple       ║ 15.00     ║        5 ║
║       3 ║ Orange      ║ 10.00     ║        2 ║
║       4 ║ Orange      ║ 11        ║        5 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

And what I would like to do is average the unit price based on the quantity.

So my desired result would be:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ ProductName ║ Average Unit Price ║ Count ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ Apple       ║ 11.67              ║    15 ║
║ Orange      ║ 10.71              ║     7 ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

You can see the data set at the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b348)

How could I do this?

Comment: `SUM(UnitPrice*Quantity)/SUM(Quantity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select productname, 
       sum(unitprice * quantity) / sum(quantity) as avg_unit_price, 
       sum(quantity) as cnt
from your_table
group by productname
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b348/1)

Comment: `[Average Unit Price]`

Comment: an sql fiddle for ms-access is not possible :D

Comment: Oh man, I am too sick for life today. Thanks for the quick answer.